# Type deduction for template references

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, type-deduction

Let's consider the following code:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T&);

int x=0;
int y=1;
f(x+y);
```

It seems that type deduction happens for this code. But why? There is no reference collapsing rule that will produce int&& at the end.

Comment: Are you by chance using MSVS?

Comment: I'm getting an error when I try to compile it, like expected

Comment: g++; clang; MSVC all report errors -  live: https://godbolt.org/z/QwHqvk

Comment: @Richard Critten But I didn't say it compiles. The question is about whether type deduction is performed before rejecting that code or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the C++17 standard, [temp.deduct.call]/3:

> ... If `P` is a reference type, the type referred to by `P` is used for type deduction. ...

Here, `P` is `T&`, so the compiler removes the reference and compares `T` with the type of the argument `x+y`. It therefore deduces `T` as `int`. Then, at the overload resolution stage, an error occurs because an rvalue of type `int` cannot be bound to the parameter of type `int&`.

Template argument deduction must occur before overload resolution, because otherwise the compiler would not know what parameter types to use for overload resolution.

Comment: Thank you. Why can't the compiler optimize the analysis and just skip overload resolution in this case (it is obvious that the template function f can't produce a function taking rvalue)? It just looks redundant.

Comment: @beginpluses Well, it's not obvious what is really going on inside the compiler. Indeed, it may have optimizations as long as those optimizations yield the same result as the standard requires, as to whether the program is well-formed or not.

Comment: @beginpluses Also, it's possible to call `f` with an argument that is an xvalue of type `const int`. In that case, `T` will be deduced as `const int` and a `const int&` can bind to an rvalue.

Comment: I didn't put it right. I was asking about why doesn't the standard require the compiler not to perform a type deduction in that case.

Comment: @beginpluses What difference would it make? The result would be the same: the program is ill-formed. Why complicate the standard to achieve the same result?

Comment: The form of the parameter is T&. No further analysis is required. Performing a type deduction looks like an unneeded complication.

Comment: @beginpluses The standard lays out a general procedure: first deduction is done, then overload resolution. You're saying the standard should be re-worded so that, under some specific conditions, this two-step analysis is skipped. However, the result would end up being the same: the program is ill-formed. Why would the standard committee add the extra wording to that effect? Just to make the compiler run a few milliseconds faster? The standard doesn't impose performance requirements on compilers.

Comment: Does that procedure apply only when the parameter type is a reference? For example, would the type deduction still be performed if the parameter type of f is T* ?

Comment: @beginpluses If the parameter type is `T*` then deduction will occur, although it is again a fairly simple form of deduction, where the compiler will just look at what type the argument points to, and deduce `T` as that type. In this case, if deduction succeeds, overload resolution must succeed as well. There are other non-reference cases where that's false, however. For example, if the parameter type is just `T` and the argument type is some non-copyable `U`, then `T` will be deduced as `U` and overload resolution will fail.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers!